# Checkbox filled TreeView appearing empty when getting its ItemsSource through Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, treeview

I've been trying to build a `TreeView` with a hierarchical setup filled with checkboxes. And such, in order to retrieve which checkboxes are checked later in the code.

Two problems are still on my plate:

1. However I try to give the `TreeView`'s `ItemsSource` as a `Binding`, the TreeView appears empty when the program is running. This does not happen if I set `ItemsSource` manually in the code-behind.
2. I also have a problem with getting the `IsChecked` information of the Checkboxes, since I can't rely on the binding.

Here's the interesting part of the code I've come up with so far:

**EDIT:**
Turned my code into something more of a minimal reproducible example per Peter Duniho's recommandations. The original source of the tree to show in the `TreeView` is an XML file. I put an emulation of the XmlDocument I get from it in the MainWindow constructor (data stored in `xmlDoc`).
Made it so the `MainWindow` implements INotifyPropertyChanged, although I don't really know how I should invoke it in the TestWindow really.
Tried setting the root node of my TagCheckboxNode tree as datacontext, didn't work much.
Tried setting the ItemsSource through the `Binding.ElementName` as well.

--- XAML ---

```
<Window x:Name="TestWindow" x:Class="WpfTests.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTests"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="350">
    <Grid>
        <TreeView x:Name="TreeView_Add_TagSelector" Margin="10,10,10,40" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=TestWindow, Path=TagCheckboxesTreeSource}">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TagCheckboxNode}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=Name}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
        <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock_Add_CurrentlySelectedTags" Margin="10,0,0,10" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Text="Currently selected tags: ---" Height="18" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

--- C# ---

```
namespace WpfTests
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc;
        TagCheckboxNode tagCheckboxesTreeSource;
        List<string> selectedTags;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            // Sample XmlDocument
            xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlElement root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
            XmlElement categories = xmlDoc.CreateElement(String.Empty, "categories", String.Empty);

            XmlElement catElement1 = xmlDoc.CreateElement(String.Empty, "category", String.Empty);
            catElement1.SetAttribute("name", "cat1");

            XmlElement tagElement11 = xmlDoc.CreateElement(String.Empty, "tag", String.Empty);
            tagElement11.SetAttribute("name", "tag11");
            catElement1.AppendChild(tagElement11);

            XmlElement tagElement12 = xmlDoc.CreateElement(String.Empty, "tag", String.Empty);
            tagElement12.SetAttribute("name", "tag12");
            catElement1.AppendChild(tagElement12);

            categories.AppendChild(catElement1);

            XmlElement catElement2 = xmlDoc.CreateElement(String.Empty, "category", String.Empty);
            catElement2.SetAttribute("name", "cat2");

            XmlElement tagElement21 = xmlDoc.CreateElement(String.Empty, "tag", String.Empty);
            tagElement21.SetAttribute("name", "tag21");
            catElement2.AppendChild(tagElement21);

            XmlElement tagElement22 = xmlDoc.CreateElement(String.Empty, "tag", String.Empty);
            tagElement22.SetAttribute("name", "tag22");
            catElement2.AppendChild(tagElement22);

            categories.AppendChild(catElement2);

            xmlDoc.AppendChild(categories);

            LoadTagTree();
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private TagCheckboxNode TagCheckboxesTreeSource
        {
            get => tagCheckboxesTreeSource;
            set
            {
                tagCheckboxesTreeSource = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TagCheckBoxTreeChanged"));
            }
        }

        private void LoadTagTree()
        {
            //ObservableCollection<TagCheckboxNode> categories = new ObservableCollection<TagCheckboxNode>();
            TagCheckboxNode categories = new TagCheckboxNode { Name = "categories" };
            foreach (XmlElement category in xmlDoc.DocumentElement)
            {
                TagCheckboxNode categoryItem = new TagCheckboxNode { Name = category.GetAttribute("name") };
                foreach (XmlElement tag in category)
                {
                    TagCheckboxNode tagItem = new TagCheckboxNode(categoryItem) { Name = tag.GetAttribute("name") };
                    categoryItem.Children.Add(tagItem);
                }
                //categories.Add(categoryItem);
                categories.Children.Add(categoryItem);
            }

            //TagCheckboxesTreeSource = categories;
            //TreeView_Add_TagSelector.ItemsSource = categories;
            this.DataContext = categories;
        }

        //private void TreeView_Add_TagSelector_Selection(object sender, DataTransferEventArgs e)
        //{
        //    selectedTags = new List<string>();
        //    // Need to get the names of the checked checkboxes into selectedTags here
        //    TextBlock_Add_CurrentlySelectedTags.Text = "Currently selected tags: " + SelectedTagsToString;
        //}

        private string SelectedTagsToString
        {
            get
            {
                string output = "";
                foreach (string tag in selectedTags) output += tag + " ";
                return output;
            }
        }
    }

    class TagCheckboxNode : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        TagCheckboxNode parent;
        ObservableCollection<TagCheckboxNode> children;
        bool? isChecked;
        bool shouldParentAlsoCheck;

        public TagCheckboxNode(TagCheckboxNode parent = null, bool shouldParentAlsoCheck = true)
        {
            this.isChecked = false;
            this.children = new ObservableCollection<TagCheckboxNode>();
            this.parent = parent;
            this.shouldParentAlsoCheck = shouldParentAlsoCheck;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<TagCheckboxNode> Children => children;
        public bool ShouldParentAlsoCheck => shouldParentAlsoCheck;
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public bool? IsChecked
        {
            get { return isChecked; }
            set { SetIsChecked(value, true, shouldParentAlsoCheck); }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        void SetIsChecked(bool? value, bool updateChildren, bool updateParent)
        {
            if (isChecked != value)
            {
                isChecked = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsChecked"));
                if (updateChildren && isChecked.HasValue)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < children.Count; i++)
                    {
                        children[i].SetIsChecked(isChecked, true, false);
                    }
                }
                if (updateParent && parent != null) parent.VerifyCheckState();
            }
        }

        void VerifyCheckState()
        {
            bool? state = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < children.Count; i++)
            {
                bool? current = children[i].IsChecked;
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    state = current;
                }
                else if (state != current)
                {
                    state = null;
                    break;
                }
            }
            SetIsChecked(state, false, shouldParentAlsoCheck);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it's not possible to know for sure what is causing the problem. However, the fact that you reset `TagCheckboxesTreeSource` after the call to `InitializeComponent()`, along with the fact that the `MainWindow` class doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` certainly _could_ explain what you're seeing. You didn't include any code that sets the data context, so it's also possible you failed to set that.

Comment: I have updated my answer to address your issue. Now that you've decided to post more context I identified another error (I see you already have fixed the binding, which looks now correct).

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the binding doesn't resolve. When you define a binding without setting the `Binding.Source`, `Binding.RelativeSource` or `Binding.ElementName`, the binding will implicitly bind to `DataContext` of the current `Binding.Target`.

In your case the `DataContext` is not set and therefore the `Binding.Source` must be set explicitly.
To set the `MainWindow` as the `Binding.Source` you can either use the `Binding.ElementName` property (when the source control is named) or the `Binding.RelativeSource` property (which will traverse the visual tree to find a matching source element):

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=MainWindow},
                        Path=TagCheckboxesTreeSource}" />
```

### Update

Now that you have fixed the data binding and posted the *MainWindow.xaml.cs*, I found another error.
The way you invoke the `PropertyChanged` event has a mistake. You are passing in the wrong property name. To prevent this silly kind of error use the `nameof` expression (which gives you compiler and IDE refactoring tool support) or the `CallerMemberName` attribute. Both solutions will support renaming of properties without breaking the notification (or any other code that relies on the string representation of the member or type).

[**nameof()**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof)
Works with any class member and with types (classes, structs, interfaces)

```
private TagCheckboxNode TagCheckboxesTreeSource
{
  get => tagCheckboxesTreeSource;
  set
  {
    tagCheckboxesTreeSource = value;
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(this.TagCheckboxesTreeSource)));
  }
}
```

[**CallerMemberNameAttribute**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute?view=netframework-4.8#examples)
Another big advantage of this solution (beside the parameterless call) is, that this event invocator works with *any* property, no matter the name or the type.
The atribute automatically gets the name of the calling member (method or property) which has invoked the method and automatically assigns it to the string parameter, which is decorated with the attribute.

```
private TagCheckboxNode TagCheckboxesTreeSource
{
  get => tagCheckboxesTreeSource;
  set
  {
    tagCheckboxesTreeSource = value;
    OnPropertyChanged(); // Invoke like this from any property setter
  }
}

protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
  this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```